# Store Map in Offline mode using PhoneGap HTML5 in XCode

Tags: xcode, html, cordova, dictionary, dojo

I'm developing an App using PhoneGap and HTML/Dojo in Xcode. This App display an Map after successful login. However, the challenge is how to load the map in case of Offline-mode? For Offline-mode the login part is handled using Local Storage feature of HTML 5. I'm looking for solution to store map in Local Storage in case of Offline-mode. Any proper solution to this problem?

Comment: What is the map technology/provider? Can you simply send a request to your server to create an image of the current map and then save that using PhoneGap's file api? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: Storing a map image will not be feasible...since the size of file will be quite large...

Comment: In my apps I used 256 colour PNG-8 map tiles for high image compression and was able to store the images offline without creating too large an app - see my [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706136/displaying-and-navigating-large-custom-maps-offline-using-phonegap?answertab=active#tab-top)