# Store map tiles inside my app

Tags: android, ios, dictionary, cordova, tile

I'm using PhoneGap (3.0) to build an Android/iOS application.

The application revolves around maps and I came to the conclusion that loading tiles from a distant service like OpenStreetMap for example is way too slow and depends too much on 3G.

**Is there a way to store tiles inside my application?**
If yes, where can I find some documentation, code snippets, etc?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether you are planning to use your own custom maps or want to use a 3rd party mapping service and therefore want to cache their tiles offline.

In the first case, I have some experience of this; I've produced a series of guided walk apps which use large custom maps I drew in Adobe Illustrator. See my [stackoverflow question and subsequent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706136/displaying-and-navigating-large-custom-maps-offline-using-phonegap) for details, but in summary I used a tool called [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/) to create highly compressed 256 colour 8-bit PNG tiles of my maps which were small enough that I could bundle several zoom levels of tiles along with each app. I ended up implementing a custom mapping solution to enable fast enough performance of map scrolling and zooming when using my Phonegap app on older Android devices.

In the latter case, if you plan to store 3rd party tiles offline, you should first check that you aren't violating the terms of use - some mapping providers specifically prohibit offline caching of their map data.

Assuming this is OK, you may want to consider using [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) to power your maps. You may want to check out [this blog article](http://tech-blog.silviaterra.com/2013/02/offline-mapping-in-html5-mobile-apps.html) on HTML5 Offline mapping and [this Phonegap-specific one](http://geospatialscott.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/phonegap-leaflet-tilemill-offline.html). Both have links to proof-of-concept apps on GitHub where the source code is available.

Hope this helps!